# set custom view not working

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have a project with multiple pages in xamrin.forms & i set my own toolbar for the actionbar with native layout in android

in some page - let's call it page3 - i want change the actionbar with a difference view, i make a custom rendrer page for page3 to set custom view for the actionbar, but its not working

my MainActivity inheritance from FormsAppCompatActivity so i try to get the actionbar from there

here is my code:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var context = ((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context);
        var actionBar = context.SupportActionBar;
        actionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.toolbar2);
    }
```

but nothing is ganged to the action bar when i switch to page3

here is my Theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

any help ??

EDIT:

here is the full rendrer - MyPage is content page for page3 :

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using asap.Droid;
using asap;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPage), typeof(NavRen))]

namespace asap.Droid
{
    public class NavRen : PageRenderer
    {


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            var context = ((FormsAppCompatActivity)Forms.Context);
            var actionBar = context.SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.toolbar2);

        }

    }

}
```

here is my custom layout called tollbar2:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

here is my default toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TitleText"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/title_logo" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Title_Sub_Icon" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Carele" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code for the renderer, and your custom layout?

Comment: i add full rendrer & layout

Comment: So all you're trying to do is change the action bar color?

Comment: i add my default toolbar layout, in page3 i want remove my defalut layout to empty tollbar & i want to use xamarin.forms navagion page titel property

Comment: Did you have any more luck with this @JokJos